# PHP - convert JAVA / JS Object to PHP array

Tags: java, php, android

I am requesting some data from Facebook over JAVA in android and sending it to the server:

```
Address[addressLines=[0:"Königspl., 86150 Augsburg, Germany"],feature=Königsplatz,admin=Bayern,sub-admin=Schwaben,locality=Augsburg,thoroughfare=Königsplatz,postalCode=86150,countryCode=DE,countryName=Germany,hasLatitude=true,latitude=48.366384499999995,hasLongitude=true,longitude=10.8943626,phone=null,url=null,extras=null]
```

I don't know what exactly this is, JAVA Object or I don't know..

I already tried: `$array = json_decode($data, true);` and it returns `NULL`

What is it and how do I convert it to PHP Array?

**EDIT:**

This is the JAVA (actually kotlin) code I use to generate the data:

```
val geocoder = Geocoder(this, Locale.ENGLISH)
try {
    val addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(48.366512, 10.894446, 1)

    if (addresses != null)
    {
        val returnedAddress = addresses[0]
        val strReturnedAddress = StringBuilder("Address:\n")
        for (i in 0 until returnedAddress.maxAddressLineIndex) {
            strReturnedAddress.append(returnedAddress.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n")
        }

        geocoderStuff = returnedAddress.toString()

    } else
    {
        // NO ADDRESS
    }
} catch (e: IOException) {
    e.printStackTrace()
}
```

And this how I send it:

```
                val params = RequestParams()
                params.put("geocoder", geocoderStuff)
                letsDoSomeNetworking(params)

private fun letsDoSomeNetworking(params: RequestParams) {

        // AsyncHttpClient belongs to the loopj dependency.
        val client = AsyncHttpClient()

        client.get("http://www.bla.com/android/fb_access.php", params, object : JsonHttpResponseHandler()
        {
            override fun onSuccess(statusCode: Int, headers: Array<Header>?, response: JSONObject?)
            {
                // success
            }

            override fun onFailure(statusCode: Int, headers: Array<Header>?, e: Throwable, response: JSONObject?)
            {
                // error
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: do you want to convert into PHP Array using Java?

Comment: I think I wouldn't be able to send it as GET to the server that easy then, I'm a beginner in android/JAVA :)

Comment: can you post the java code that is used for sending data to server?

Comment: Ok I edited the question

Comment: try to use `$_GET['geocoder']` on `json_decode`. see if it works or not.

Comment: this is what I tried :D don't work that way

Comment: how about this? `$array = json_decode($_REQUEST['geocoder'], true);`

Comment: Nope don't work that way, it also don't look like JSON, JSON is always having {} ??

Comment: Whatever it is, it's not JSON. In JSON all strings must be quoted with double quotes. Arrays are only numerical, not hash tables arrays, like PHP has. And in JSON values are not set using an `=` sign, but a `:`.

Comment: @FrankBank JSON uses `{}` for objects and `[]` for arrays.

Comment: Thanks I already got the solution and it's kotlin/Java side

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to use gson library on JAVA/Kotlin side after getting the data:

```
        val returnedAddress = addresses[0]
        val strReturnedAddress = StringBuilder("Address:\n")
        for (i in 0 until returnedAddress.maxAddressLineIndex) {
            strReturnedAddress.append(returnedAddress.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n")
        }

        val gson = Gson() // HERE
        val json = gson.toJson(returnedAddress) // HERE

        geocoderStuff = json
```